# Still show div when textarea/input onblur / loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, onblur, onfocus

so I try to hide/show a div element with using onfocus and onblur:

```
<textarea onfocus="document.getElementById('divID1').style.display='block';" onblur="document.getElementById('divID1').style.display='none';"></textarea>
<div id="divID1">
```

This works fine, but the problem is that the div hides again when the textarea/input doesn't have focus anymore.

This is the whole code: [JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQfN/1/).
You can see that you can't check the Checkbox or select text.

What can I do to still display the div element when the textarea lost focus or to make the textarea still having focus when I clicked on the div?

Sorry, but I'm new to Javascript.

Thanks in advance,
Philipp

Comment: I don't understand, you want to hide it onblur, but keep it displayed off focus??

Comment: No, I want to hide it if you click outside of the div or of the textarea. Like the textarea and the div would be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not trivial, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to/124560#124560), it can be solved in the following way:

**HTML**

```html
<textarea id="example1" onfocus="focushandler('divID1');"></textarea>
<br />
<textarea id="example2" onfocus="focushandler('divID2');"></textarea>
<br />

<div id="divID1">
    <p>This div is blue</p>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox A
</div>
<div id="divID2">
    <p>This div is green</p>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox B
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
var current = null; //currently shown div - divID1 or divID2

function focushandler(id) {
    if (current !== null) {
        current.style.display = 'none';
    }
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = 'block';
    current = div;
}

function clickhandler(e) {
    if (current == null) { //if both divs are hidden
        return;
    }
    e = e || window.event; //for IE8,7 compatibility
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement; // clicked element
    var sig = false;
    // now check all parents
    while (t) {
        if (t === current || t.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA') {
            sig = true;
        }
        t = t.parentNode;
    }
    if (sig) {
        return;
    }
    current.style.display = 'none';
    current = null;
}

if (document.documentElement.addEventListener) {
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', clickhandler, false);
} else if (document.documentElement.attachEvent) { // for IE8-7 compatibility
    document.documentElement.attachEvent('onclick', clickhandler);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQfN/4/show): http://jsfiddle.net/PfQfN/4/ (works good with Firefox, Chrome, IE7-10, Safari and Opera). Or alternatively you can use this a bit modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/PfQfN/6/ (the effects are the same).

Updated CSS: And according to [this very useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588309/static-elements-after-positionabsolute#9301426), those elements can be positioned better as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQfN/9/show): http://jsfiddle.net/PfQfN/9/

Answer (score 0):

By adding a very short delay (setTimeout) on the blur action the checkbox works.
For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('divID2').style.display='none';
}, 100);
```

Here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQfN/2/).

Comment: That's cool, but is there no way to keep the div constantly there until you click outside of the textarea or of the div?