# CSS - Auto height of an element containing absolute positioned children?

Tags: css

on the site I am currently developing I have a `<nav>` element containing a 2 leveled `<ul>`, I am absolute positioning the sub list (`nav ul li ul`) to the right of the main list.

The problem I am having is when the sub list is longer (taller) than the main list, due to the sub list being absolutely positioned, the  element is not stretching to accommodate it. See the below image for an example of what I mean.

[image]

My HTML is as follows:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">List 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav><!-- /nav -->
```

Any idea of a solution to this? Ideally I would like to keep it as a nested list for semantic reasons.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Please see the following jsFiddle for a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/TcYBQ/

Comment: Can you add your current CSS + make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to a jsFiddle

Comment: A similar question that could help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650539/how-to-clear-absolutely-positioned-elements

Comment: There's no way (well, there's JavaScript) to do what you want without moving "List 2" in the HTML and then not using absolute positioning. Visually, "List 2" appears to be nothing to do with "List 1", so why should it be nested inside?

Comment: I'm using the lists as the navigation on the site, so the list on the right is all the subpages of the second list item on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I used a variation of the jQuery in the question linked to by @derekerdmann

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('#top nav ul').each(function () {
    var tmpHeight = $(this).height() + $(this).position().top;

    if (tmpHeight > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = tmpHeight;
        $('#top nav').height(maxHeight + 20);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't satisfy all your constraints at the same time:

- The parent element must have the correct height.
- No JavaScript.
- In the HTML, "List 2" must be inside "List 1".

To have the correct height on the parent, you can't use absolute positioning on "List 2". Unfortunately, there's then no other way to move "List 2" to where it should be.

Pick from these:

- Use JavaScript to set the height and keep the semantic HTML.
- Move "List 2" out of "List 1" and avoid JavaScript but sacrifice the semantic HTML.

I'd try to avoid JavaScript for this, unless the rest of the site is highly reliant upon it.

Comment: I've actually gone for the JavaScript option, as I'd like to maintain the semantics for tabbing order etc. Thanks for the response.